# "Found @client directives in query but no client resolvers were specified" Warning when using client cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I've been following the [Apollo Client docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state) on local state.

I've implemented a very simple query of the client cache:

```
export const GET_USER_ACCOUNTS = gql`
    query GetUserAccounts {
        userAccounts @client
        name @client
    }
`;
```

`userAccounts` and `name` are both stored in my cache following authentication:

```js
    <Mutation
          mutation={API_TOKEN_AUTHENTICATION}
          variables={{ apiKey }}
          onCompleted={({
              apiTokenAuthentication: {
                  token,
                  userAccounts,
                  user: { givenName, familyName },
               },
          }) => {
             localStorage.setItem('token', token);
             client.writeData({
                 data: {
                     isLoggedIn: true,
                     userAccounts,
                     name: `${givenName} ${familyName}`,
                 },
             });
         }}
    >
```

and I've warmed the cache with default values:

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';

const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const link = new HttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:8002/v1/graphql',
    headers: {
        Authorization: `${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
    },
});
const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    link,
});
// set up the initial state
cache.writeData({
    data: {
        name: '',
        userAccounts: [],
        isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem('token'),
    },
});

export default client;
```

I've not included any local resolvers, since the docs state:

> When Apollo Client executes this query and tries to find a result for the isInCart field, it runs through the following steps:
>
> Has a resolver function been set (either through the ApolloClient constructor resolvers parameter or Apollo Client's setResolvers / addResolvers methods) that is associated with the field name isInCart? If yes, run and return the result from the resolver function.
>
> If a matching resolver function can't be found, check the Apollo Client cache to see if a isInCart value can be found directly. If so, return that value.

However, despite the code working fine (it fetches the values I want no problem) I still get this warning:

> Found @client directives in query but no client resolvers were specified. You can now pass apollo-link-state resolvers to the ApolloClient constructor.

Have I misunderstood? Should I be including a client resolver for this in some way?

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state#client-fields-cache):

> ⚠️ If you want to use Apollo Client's `@client` support to query the cache without using local resolvers, you must pass an empty object into the `ApolloClient` constructor `resolvers` option. Without this Apollo Client will not enable its integrated `@client` support, which means your `@client` based queries will be passed to the Apollo Client link chain. You can find more details about why this is necessary [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/4499).

In other words, just add an empty resolvers object to your configuration like this:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    link,
    resolvers: {},
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try this but I still get the warning

Comment: I take it back - of course that works, it just haven't included a client in my MockedProvider, so still got the warning in my test. Thanks so much!

Comment: I can ask this as another question, but I added the client here  `<MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false} client={client}>` and still get the warning in my test. Do you happen to know where I can plug it in please?

Comment: [Looks like](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/blob/master/src/test-utils.tsx#L11-L19) `resolvers` should be passed directly to `MockedProvider`. Which makes sense -- you might want to swap out the resolvers for testing.

Answer (score 6):

As Daniel later mentioned in the [comments of the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970271/found-client-directives-in-query-but-no-client-resolvers-were-specified-warni#comment98593824_55970913), passing `resolvers={{}}` inside of `MockedProvider` worked wonderfully for me. Here's how it should look like:

```
<MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false} resolvers={{}}>
    <FooComponent />
</MockedProvider>
```

It even solved a memory leakage problem I was having in Circle CI, as it seems there was nowhere to resolve to; here are the error messages I was getting:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  154665 ms: Mark-sweep 949.1 (1434.4) -> 948.2 (1434.4) MB, 1979.3 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  156664 ms: Mark-sweep 948.2 (1434.4) -> 948.2 (1434.4) MB, 1999.7 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  158734 ms: Mark-sweep 948.2 (1434.4) -> 948.2 (1434.4) MB, 2069.7 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
  160810 ms: Mark-sweep 948.2 (1434.4) -> 948.1 (1434.4) MB, 2075.7 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x30ab306c9fa9 <JS Object>
    2: convertPropertyValueToJson(aka convertPropertyValueToJson) [/home/circleci/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:24737] [pc=0x2953c91d9878] (this=0x30ab30604189 <undefined>,valueExpression=0x39effa032fa9 <a NodeObject with map 0x35eb62463c11>,option=0x30ab30604189 <undefined>)
    3: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [/home/circleci/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/type...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Cheers!